# DataGridView won't load

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I tried a lot to get around this problem,
Basically, I'm checking if someone has the same country id as the one set in the combobox, if so, I add some information regarding them on the DataGridView below,
but It seemed to not work, I debuged the conditions and all, but I still didn't know what could be wrong with it,

```
public partial class Form_ListJ : Form
{
    public Form_ListJ()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        comboBox_ListJ.DataSource = Form_Menu.dataSet.Tables["Pays"];
        comboBox_ListJ.DisplayMember = "nomPays";
        comboBox_ListJ.ValueMember = "idPays";
        comboBox_ListJ.SelectedIndex = -1;
    }

    private void comboBox_ListJ_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        dataGridView_ListJ.Rows.Clear();

        foreach (DataRow dataRow_J in Form_Menu.dataSet.Tables["Joueur"].Rows)
        {
            if (dataRow_J[7] == comboBox_ListJ.SelectedValue)
                dataGridView_ListJ.Rows.Add(dataRow_J[0], dataRow_J[1], dataRow_J[2]);
        }
    }
}
```

dataRow_J[7] is the field of 'idPays' inside of the 'Joueur' table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to convert values to string 
like this

```
if (dataRow_J[0].ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a bunch, however,
when I add `comboBox_ListJ.SelectedIndex = -1;`, it gives an error

Comment: if (comboBox1.SelectedValue!=null)
            {
                dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
                foreach (DataRow dataRow_J in ds.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    if (dataRow_J[0].ToString() == comboBox1.SelectedValue.ToString())
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(dataRow_J[0], dataRow_J[1], dataRow_J[2]);
                }
            }